# Internet Explorer not authenticating user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer

I'm working on this little MVC project which is taking shape quite well. Just now I figured I'd test it in Internet explorer, and it shows some strange behavior for which I don't really know where to look for the cause/solution.

It's live here: [www.begijnhof.net/CodeBox](http://www.begijnhof.net/CodeBox)

In FireFox, IE on my WP7 phone, safari on iphone or Chrome, you register/login, and it takes you to the homepage, that then shows you extra buttons in the top left of the page.

In IE, when you provide proper credentials `(user/user1*)`, i think it authenticates, since it doesn't show any errors, and does when you provide wrong credentials. Yet it does not show the buttons etc.

After testing it some more it works, eventho I delete all the cookies etc, yet tomorrow or so it won't work again some time soon.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on this one? Thanks..

Okay, sorry for that:
I was thinking about a second problem, wrong code! So the login process is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(LogOnViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (members.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false);
                return RedirectToAction("List", "Snippet");
            }

            //Check to see what's wrong 
            if (userRepo.IsUserLockedOut(model.Username))
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Authentication failed!");
            if (userRepo.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == model.Username) == null)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "User does not exists!");
            if (!userRepo.IsUserLockedOut(model.Username) && userRepo.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == model.Username) != null)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The password is not correct!");
            return View(model);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Edit: I think I found what's causing it, but no solution tho.

The domain it's under has cloaking, so the URL is always /CodeBox, and that is causing some problems.

Comment: You should provide the code for the authentication and the handling of the display if that's what your question is about. Otherwise we'd just be guessing as to what the problem actually is.

Comment: What is the code that shows/hides the buttons?

Comment: It seems that when I put a breakpoint on my IsUserInRole method in my CustomRoleProvider, it doesn't get there when I refresh my page, or navigate around. I'm taking a deeper look this direction..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this:

```
if (members.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password)) 
{ 
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false);
    return RedirectToAction("List", "Snippet"); 
}
```

Setting the second parameter of `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` to false means the cookie won't persist across browser sessions.  That means if you close the browser, the cookie is removed.  Try setting that to true instead:

```
if (members.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password)) 
{ 
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, true);
    return RedirectToAction("List", "Snippet"); 
}
```